# Load XML File from Project Directory

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in my WPF project an "assets" folder by the fonts, images and XML files. How can I read XML files from the project directory using C#? Tried it on the Assembly, but the file can not be found. About XAML can very easily download images from that folder.

When I use the follow string, the file can't be found. How can I load my XML file from the project directory?

```
string stream = "pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/assets/myxml.xml";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why dont you put your file in project resource, this way it will be embeded in the assembly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution to load your file, using Linq to Xml, is:

```
XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(@"assets\myxml.xml");
```

Comment: and make sure you have set "Copy To Output directory" to true. i always miss that and wonder why it doesnt work :)

Comment: Where must set "Copy To Output Directory"? In XDocument?

Comment: If you right click on your xml file in Solution Navigator and select properties you should see the option.

Answer (score 3):

After search in deep and deep web:

Set the "Build Action" property for the XML file to "Embedded Resource".

And use:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.FolderName.XmlArchive.xml"));
```

=D

Answer (score 0):

I've got a very similar issue, I was not able to load file from folder in project structure. All settings were correct, but still it was returning IO error.

All answers abow are probably correct - but in my case it still want to load file. There is a need to change one property more:

- Build Action = Embedded Resource
- Copy to Output Directory = Copy always

Without setting it as "Embedded Resource" it was not reachable from my program. After change it is working.

Answer (score -1):

string strAppPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(strAppPath +"ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");