# Access XAML Resources in cs

Tags: c#, xaml, resources

App.xaml

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="ListData" Source="Resources\ListData.xml" XPath="/Data"/>
```

I'm able to access this everywhere in xaml.

But...
MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
InitializeComponent();
model.SetResource(this.FindResource("ListData"));
```

In the constructors  `App()` and `MainWindow()`, this.Resources.Count = 0.  `this.FindResource("ListData")` returns an object with the right `Source` but null `Data` and `Document`.

- Source  {Resources\ListData.xml}    System.Uri

Model.cs:

```
    internal void SetResource(object v)
    {
        _listData = (System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider)v;
        _listData.InitialLoad();
    }
```

This runs with no exceptions or errors returned, but no data is produced.

```
_listData.Error null    System.Exception
_listData.Document  null    System.Xml.XmlDocument
_listData.Data  null    object
```

How do I share a resource between XAML and cs?

---

The [file property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx) `Build Action` is set as `Resource`.  Which should imply that the file is in the manifest under "namespace.filename.extension, where namespace is the value of the DefaultNamespace property in a Visual C# project".

I failed to find it with the following:

```
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.Reflection.ManifestResourceInfo listDataInfo = assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo("MyNamespace.ListData.xml");
```

Comment: There is a similar issue presented here, but I don't want to copy the resource to the output directory:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6151003/2091951

Comment: If I make the Build Action EmbeddedResource it shows up in `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` but is no longer accessible in xaml.

Comment: There may be an additional solution using ResourceManager. 
 See attached project:  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/835140/one-more-time-about-resource-vs-embeddedresource

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This really feels like a hack, but it does seem to work.  You could use any carrier control for this, I just happen to need a ComboBox...

in .xaml file

```
<ComboBox Loaded="List_Port_Loaded" Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListData}, XPath=Valves}" />
```

in .cs file

```
    private void List_Port_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlElement valveXML = ((ComboBox)sender).Tag as XmlElement;
    }
```

I'd be willing to accept a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

App.xaml:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="ListData" Source="Resources\ListData.xml" XPath="/Data" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" IsAsynchronous="False"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
InitializeComponent();
model.SetListData((this.FindResource("ListData") as System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider).Document);
```

This XmlDocument is fully populated.

[Reference: How-to access XmlDataProvider's data as XmlDocument from code behind?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/595c90f9-513d-487b-a937-4f7045705ee7/howto-access-xmldataproviders-data-as-xmldocument-from-code-behind?forum=wpf)